# CRON jobs in php deployed in windows platform

Tags: php, cron, scheduling

How to run a scheduled job scripted in php using windows?  I'm using Windows XP sp3.

Comment: Voting to migrate to superuser. Also, which Windows version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Use `at` or the task scheduler.

- [How To Use the AT Command to Schedule Tasks](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/31356) (seems to require login now - wtf?)
- Alternative: [Wikipedia on AT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_%28Windows%29)
- [How To Schedule Tasks in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569)

You would have to call the PHP interpreter from the command line. In Windows, it is called `php.exe`. You'll have to find out where it resides, usually in the Programs folder or a sub-directory of your server installation.

The command line for the call will then be something like

```
"C:\Program Files\Xampp\PHP\PHP.exe" -f "c:\htdocs\my_script_to_run.php"
```

Note that PHP will probably use a different `php.ini` file when called this way, and some variables (like `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]`) are not available. This way of running PHP is called CLI (Command Line Interface).

To determine within a PHP script whether it is being run on the Web server or from the command line, use [php_sapi_name()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php).

Comment: @Arup both `at` and the scheduler are available for you then. Check them out.

Answer (score -1):

Note that PHP will probably use a different php.ini file when called this way, and some variables (like $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]) are not available. This way of running PHP is called CLI (Command Line Interface).