# how to send emails automatically on certain day or time in php?

Tags: php

I developed a site for user registration but I need a functionality that I have never experienced. The functionality I need is to send an email to a user who has just signed up, with a .pdf file attached. After 15 days of registration, an email will be sent automatically to that user. Please guide me how can I do this thing in PHP with a mySQL database.

Comment: learn about Cron jobs.

Answer (score 4):

You can use CRON Jobs for this. Create a script and schedule it in your server using cron jobs. 
http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml

Most widely used hosting panel is cPanel, you can see a guide here.
http://www.greengeeks.com/support/video-tutorials/display.php?tname=cpanel-x3-cronjob
[Run a PHP file in a cron job using CPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332804/run-a-php-file-in-a-cron-job-using-cpanel)
http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/CronJobs

Comment: hmmmm, peoples around suggested me the same however, I have found cron jobs are only done in linux based OS and I am doing windows based platform that supports task scheduling so how can I fixed that problem?

Comment: Probably this might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491378/cron-jobs-in-php-deployed-in-windows-platform

Comment: it's also worth mentioning that each state has a different time vs server time. this might lead to a mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

write your code logic in separate php file apart from your application and try setting **Corn job**.

[How to send emails via cron job usng PHP mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368307/how-to-send-emails-via-cron-job-usng-php-mysql)

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

Comment: sorry to notify you that i am using windows platform.